# Is there any way to change the background color of material-ui tab indicator on hover and active state of Tab

Tags: material-ui

Is there any way to change the background color of material-ui tab indicator on hover and the active state of Tab.

Default state
[image]

On hover I would like to style tab indicator like this
[image]

I couldn't find any way using css to modify like this. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the style rules for the tab indicator and hover/selected-state tab, [here's the demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/customized-materialui-tabs-demo-kouf3?file=/demo.js:1500-2116):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  indicator: {
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
  },
  tabRoot: {
    "&:hover": {
      color: "yellow",
      opacity: 1
    }
  },
  selectedTab: {
    color: "yellow"
  }
 }));
```

---

```
<Tabs classes={{ indicator: classes.indicator }}>
    <Tab
      classes={{ root: classes.tabRoot, selected: classes.selectedTab }}
      label="Item One"
    />
    <Tab
      classes={{ root: classes.tabRoot, selected: classes.selectedTab }}
      label="Item Two"
    />
    <Tab
      classes={{ root: classes.tabRoot, selected: classes.selectedTab }}
      label="Item Three"
    />
</Tabs>
```

Comment: Thanks @dongnhan. This solution is for the active state, But I was looking for the "hover" state.

Comment: Hi @Raghav, I've updated the solution and the demo, check it out.